# How to set the entire date/time for an instance?

Tags: momentjs

I'm adding an extension function to Moment and it needs to change the entire Moment instance to a new date/time value.  However, the available Set methods only seem to allow setting specific units (ie. day, month, hour, second).

I understand that it would probably be possible to do:

```
this.set('year', year);
this.set('month', month);
...
```

but this seems ugly and possibly error-prone (if the values adjust for temporarily invalid date/times).

Answer (score 0):

You can get Date from that moment values and then use setMinutes, setYear, setMonth etc. functions on that date object.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I already proposed in my question.  The problem with this is that Moment adjusts the date to always ensure it's valid so: `var a = Moment(new Date('Feb 20, 2014')); a.date(31); a.month(7);`.  Now a is Aug 03, 2014.  Alternatively, `var a = Moment(new Date('July 31, 2014')); a.month(1); a.date(31);`.  Now a is Mar 03, 2014.  Either case it's not what was desired.